# Haskell Cartesian Product, Monad with filter

Tags: haskell, filter, monads

This has to be dead simple and I'm unhappy I can't figure it out at this point in my Haskell experience. I want a cartesian product of a list with itself, but I want to filter out identical items. I don't want a post filter.

This gets me the CP - seemingly set up to simply add a filter...

```
p as bs = do
            a <- as
            b <- bs
            return (a,b)

p [1,2,3] [1,2,3]
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

I have read that `return ()` is basically a noop in do notation - but this doesn't compile. (Are the tuples being mixed up)

```
pf as bs = do
            a <- as
            b <- bs
            if a == b then return () else return (a,b)

* Couldn't match type `()' with `(a, a)'
      Expected type: [(a, a)]
        Actual type: [()]
```

I have tried a few other things, like the `if'` function from the Haskell wiki. I also tried `when` without success. When the filter is `when`

```
when (a /= b) return (a,b)

* Couldn't match type `m0 (a, a)' with `()'
      Expected type: (a, a) -> ()
        Actual type: (a, a) -> m0 (a, a)
```

I suppose these error messages are leading me by the nose to the issue but I am not adept at translating most of them yet.

There is very possibly a higher level function that might handle this in a more straight forward way (filterM ?), and I'll be happy to hear about its usage, but I still want to know how to solve this issue in the `pf` function above.

Thanks

Comment: You might as well use a list comprehension: `[(a, b) | a <- as, b <- bs, a == b]`.

Comment: Thanks for the "more straight forward way".

Comment: It's not a no-op at all. `return () == [()]` in the case of the list monad. What you read was probably specific to typical usage of the `IO` monad. For example, `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`, which creates an IO action that, when executed, writes some characters to standard output and produces the value `()`. Since no body actually cares about the value produced by executing an action of type `IO ()`, `return ()` is a no-op in the sense that the action it creates does no input or output; it only produces the expected and required value of `()`.

Comment: I have a different take than chepner: `return ()` *can* be reasonably thought of as a no-op, even in the list monad. BUT the other half of your branch *isn't* a no-op, and actually returns a value of some interesting type. A no-op isn't a suitable alternative; it doesn't return a value of that interesting type (and, in the list monad in particular, doesn't even return *no* values of that interesting type -- try to wrap your brain around that double negative!).

Comment: `return ()` is a no-op in the sense that `do { a <- as ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) }` == `do { return () ; a <- as ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) }` = `do { a <- as ; return () ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) }` = `do { a <- as ; b <- bs ; return () ; return (a,b) }`. you can put it on any line of the `do` block except the last one and it won't change a thing. this is true for _any_ monad. (cc @chepner)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```hs
main = print $ p [1,2,3] [1,2,3] -- [(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)]

p as bs =
  do
    a <- as
    b <- bs
    if a == b then [] else return (a, b)
```

I've learned Haskell a bit only recently, so I may be wrong. In this context, `return (a, b)` is nothing more than the expression `[(a, b)]` (which is natural, since for monad `[]` you need a function with the output of type `[t]`). So you need to provide the same type, i.e., the empty list `[]`.

On the other hand when you write `return ()` it actually is `[()]`, whose type is `[()]`, which is not the same as, say, the type `[(Int, Int)]`.

Comment: I learned something. I did not know that ```return (a,b)``` was equivalent to ```[(a,b)]```. I was under the impression ```return``` had to be used to lift a value into the output context (I read things way to literally sometimes). Thanks

Comment: Other examples `return  a = Just a` for Maybe, `return a = Right a` for Either. We can also observe that `Applicative f => Monad f`, making `return = pure`.

Comment: @user49011 It does. The `do` notation desugars to `as >>= \a -> bs >>= \b -> if a == b then [] else return (a, b)`. `return` must produce a list for the conditional expression to type check. It's the definition of `>>=` that cause the expression (with different values of `a` and `b` each time) to be evaluated multiple times. For lists, that simply means lifting the tuple `(a, b)` into a list `[(a, b)]`. Intuitively, `return` has to produce the simplest non-trivial value of the correct type.

Comment: (You might think, "`[]` is simpler than `[(a, b)]`", but in the context of the monad laws, `[]` isn't non-trivial.)

Comment: @chepner you _can't_ create `[]`-datum using only `[]`-type-monad functions. you need MonadPlus for that (or use `[]`-datum literal in one of the actions).

Comment: (IOW monad laws know nothing about the existence of `mzero`, which the `[]`-datum is. I don't think they know anything about the existence of `fail "" :: [()]` either.)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`Control.Monad.guard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) instead of using `[]` directly.

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

p as bs =
  do
    a <- as
    b <- bs
    guard $ a /= b
    return (a, b)
```

You can think this as a `do`-notation version of the list-comprehension `[(a, b) | a <- as, b <- bs, a /= b]`.

Comment: Note that `guard True == [()]` and `guard False == []`. Because of how the list monad is defined, only the difference between an empty and non-empty list matters, not the actual contents of the list returned by `guard`.

Comment: (Namely, `guard x >> return (a, b) == guard x >>= \_ -> return (a, b)`, and since Haskell is lazy, `\_ -> return (a, b)` only gets called if the list it is bound to contains a value. `[()]` can supply an argument (which is ignored), but `[]` does not.

Comment: @chepner - I really appreciate all your comments on the various posts here. They are pointing out pretty big holes in my knowledge and give me plenty of avenues to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your

```
pf as bs = do
             a <- as
             b <- bs
             if a == b then return () else return  (a,b)
```

by changing it to

```
pf2 :: (Monad m, Eq t) => m t -> m t -> m [(t, t)]
pf2 as bs = do
             a <- as
             b <- bs
             if a == b then return [] else return [(a,b)]
```

In case the `m` is `[]`-type, this gets us

```
pf3 :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [ [(t, t)] ]
pf3 as bs = do
             a <- as
             b <- bs
             if a == b then return [] else return [(a,b)]
```

so it does pass the type-checker now, but we've created an extra layer of `[]` around our desired type:

```
> pf3 [1,2,3] [1,2,3] :: [ [(Int,Int)] ]
[[],[(1,2)],[(1,3)], [(2,1)],[],[(2,3)], [(3,1)],[(3,2)],[]]
```

So this is almost what we wanted, except for some extra `[]`s thrown around for good measure. If only we could make them disappear,

```
> concat it
[    (1,2),  (1,3),   (2,1),     (2,3),   (3,1),  (3,2)    ]
```

we'd get what we really wanted as the end result.

As you can see above we did get the final desired value, by passing the output of `pf3` through *`concat`*. But `concat` is `[]`-type-monad's `join`:

```
> :t concat :: [] ([] a) -> [] a
concat ::       [] ([] a) -> [] a   :: [[a]] -> [a]

> :t join ::   [] ([] a) -> [] a
join ::         [] ([] a) -> [] a   :: [[a]] -> [a]

> :t join
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

which is defined as

```
join xs = do                    = do
           { x <- xs               { x <- xs
           ; x                     ; y <- x
           }                       ; return y
                                   }
```

and thus what we wrote above fuses together as

```
pf4 as bs = join $ do
                     a <- as
                     b <- bs
                     if a == b then return [] else return [(a,b)]
    = do {
           x <- do { a <- as
                   ; b <- bs
                   ; if a == b then return [] else return [(a,b)] }
         ; x 
         }
    = do {           a <- as
                   ; b <- bs
         ; x <-      if a == b then return [] else return [(a,b)]
         ; x
         }
    = do { a <- as
         ; b <- bs
         ; let { x = if a == b then  []  else  [(a,b)]  }
         ; x
         }
    = do { a <- as
         ; b <- bs
         ;      if a == b then  []  else  [(a,b)]
         }
    = do { a <- as
         ; b <- bs
         ;      if a == b then  []  else  [()]
         ; return (a,b)
         }
```

whichever of the last two you prefer. The first of the two is what you'd normally write out by hand, and the last corresponds to using `reject (a==b)` as the third `do` line, with the definition

```
reject :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()
reject True  = mzero         -- mzero :: MonadPlus m => m a
reject False = return ()     -- () to be ignored
```

where for the `[]`-type monad, `mzero = [] :: [] a` (and of course, `return x = [x] :: [] a`).

It so happens that `reject b = guard (not b)`, with the built-in `guard`.

---

A side remark:

`return ()` is a no-op in the sense that

```
do {             a <- as ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) } ==
do { return () ; a <- as ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) } ==
do { a <- as ; return () ; b <- bs ; return (a,b) } ==
do { a <- as ; b <- bs ; return () ; return (a,b) }
```

You can put it on any line of the `do` block except the last one and it won't change a thing. This is true for *any* monad.